What can I input under the Object type in Azure Ai Studio's Prompt Flow?

Not sure if it's mentioned in any official documentation but what can I input in Azure Ai Studio's prompt flow that has the "Object" type?
Can I put a file as an "Object" input? If yes, how do I do it?


Can I put a file as an "Object" input? If yes, how do I do it?

Directly uploading a file as an "Object" input isn't natively supported. Instead, Convert the file into a Base64 string and include this string in a JSON object.

Here, I use python function tool in my Azure AI prompt flow.


Test_Node.py:
from promptflow import tool
import base64

@tool
def my_python_tool(input1: dict) -> str:
    # Check if input1 is valid and contains required keys
    if not input1 or 'file_name' not in input1 or 'file_data' not in input1:
        return "Invalid input: Missing 'file_name' or 'file_data'."

    file_name = input1.get("file_name")
    file_data_base64 = input1.get("file_data")

    if not file_name or not file_data_base64:
        return "Invalid input: 'file_name' or 'file_data' cannot be None."

    try:
        # Decode the Base64 encoded file data (even if we don't use it)
        file_data = base64.b64decode(file_data_base64).decode('utf-8')
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error decoding file data: {str(e)}"

    # Create a static response string
    response = "Hello boss, I am back!"
    
    return response


Pass this JSON object as the "Object" input.

{
    "file_name": "example.txt",
    "file_data": "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh"
}

Output:

In this way, we can be able to input complex data structures into the prompt flow to provide richer context and also handle more advanced scenarios.
